# Angular JS : Controller properties not shown in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS. Sorry for this simple question.

I have learnt something from this tutorial: http://courseware.codeschool.com/shaping-up-with-angular-js/Slides/level01-05.pdf

And I have tried an example. This is not working. **http://jsfiddle.net/89wfv/1/**

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="main">
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="con">

        <div>{{con.desc}}</div>
        <input type='button' ng-click='getDesc();' value='Get name' />
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("main", []);

    app.controller("con", function() {

        this.desc = "test description";

        this.getDesc = function() {
            alert(this.desc);
        }

    });

})();
```

Problem is showing description in div and alert description by click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot controller as something

```
<div ng-controller="con as ctrl">

    <div>{{ctrl.desc}}</div>
    <input type='button' ng-click='ctrl.getDesc();' value='Get name' />
</div>
```

take a look at the guide instead :

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

works:

http://jsfiddle.net/pYh89/

you didnt load angular correctly and add several syntax errors.

```
var app = angular.module("main", []);
app.controller("con", function () {

    this.name = 'foo';

    this.getName = function () {
        alert("foo");
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Still it's not working... Can you please provide answer in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/89wfv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS is missing in your code please include it after downloading it.

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

You can also use online version.

Comment: What about the fiddle version? It has the Angular included but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I have included AngularJS 1.2.1 in jsfiddle. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot different things:

Here's a corrected JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/89wfv/2/

You have to:

- Use `$scope` instead of `this` to reference to the data that is to be bound to the view, eg:

  ```
  app.controller("con", function($scope) {

     $scope.name = 'vasu';

     $scope.getName = function() {
         alert();
     }

  });
  ```
- Put the script tag in Head
- Not use the html tag, that could be overwritten by JSfiddle:

Do rather something like this:

```
<div ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="con">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in that tutorial they are showing the 'controller as' syntax, where you do set properties on `this`.

Comment: Ok, didn't know it was even possible.